# How to filter a list of items in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

I have list store in mysql table file1=(1,2,3,4,6,7) and other list file2 = (3,2,4,8,9,10,12) is not stored in table, i want compare both and result should be like 
result=(6,7,8,9,10,12) then calculate the percentage. like 100*(result/file1+file2) in mysql data structure. i do not know how i will do it.
please know body know guide me or give me a small example.
thanks

Comment: Are you talking about a database only solution?

Comment: Are you sure of the result??? Shouldn't it be (1,6,7,8,9,10,12)???

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table to store the "other" list that is not already in a table, and then use a join or union to get the result you want.

If you are wanting to select the values that are not in either list, then you can use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` to count the occurrence of each number, and then `HAVING` to select those rows with a count of 1.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can easily do that in pure sql. you need a procedural language to get the result in the first list, merge, sort, unique with the second list and compute the result.